# Fragment on create view and on view created alternative in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-jetpack-compose

In Fragment lifecycle, we have `onCreateView` and `onViewCreated`.

What is the correct alternative for these lifecycle methods in jetpack compose?

Should I use `LaunchedEffect(true)` for both or are there different ways to handle these lifecycle callbacks?

**Edit 1**.
The main focus of this question is to understand if there is any difference in handling those two fragment lifecycle methods.

The taged question does not explicitly answer my question.
Philip's comment below does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are Android activities handled with Jetpack Compose and Compose Navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68962458/how-are-android-activities-handled-with-jetpack-compose-and-compose-navigation)

Comment: Shortly, yes, `LaunchedEffect` is the compose way of doing that. In declarative way there's no need to listen `onViewCreated`, because you can declare all needed composables with relationships without waiting it to be "created"

Comment: Your last comment was what I was looking for. To confirm if there is any difference between handling these two methods. Thanks. 
BTW - Your answers on jetpack compose questions help me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the declarative way there's no need to listen `onViewCreated`, because you can declare all needed composables with relationships without waiting it to be "created" or rendered.

And yes, `LaunchedEffect` is the compose way of doing that.