# Are Fragments useless with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

As far as I know, before jetpack-compose, It was good practice to have one single activity and then use multiple fragments for your app.
But now jetpack compose offers navigation between jetpack compose functions so do we need fragments now?
or we can just use single activity with multiple screens(compose functions)
if we don't need fragments anymore, how I could do stuff like add/edit in the database, getting context, etc. while using only single activity and compose functions.
I'm still a beginner/learning so I might be missing something or doing something wrong.

Comment: "so do we need fragments now? or we can just use single activity with multiple screens(compose functions)" -- you do not need fragments, [though you can use them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69143770/115145). "how I could do stuff like add/edit in the database, getting context, etc" -- if you really want answers here for that, ask individual focused questions. Otherwise, there are lots of existing articles and other educational resources. I list a dozen or two of them [every week](https://jetc.dev).