# Jetpack Compose, using new Activity or new Navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm here looking for the best practices in Jetpack Compose, what is more best practice, work using new Activity (by using intent)

```kotlin
startActivity(Intent(this, AnotherActivity::class.java))
```

or using [Jetpack Compose Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)?

and please show me the example why it will be best practice like, Time Compile, or Memory to run the app.

Thank you for your answer...

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68962907/3585796)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetpack Compose is built for single activity architecture what that means is you only have one activity and use compose navigation for navigating in your apps it is much easier also but if you need to use multiple activities you can but the data passing falls on your hands you need to take care of it.