# where should I release my resources like Media Player when using Navigating in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I wrote my app with Jetpack Compose and navigation component. Also using MVVM.
I have a single activity with five screen.
when user enter to list screen1 from home screen, maybe play a sound.
I want to stop and release Media Player when user press back and leave screen.
because of Navigating with Compose, there is no fragments , I have just composable screen associate with view model.
now I wondering where should I release my resources like Media Player?
because Media Player is UI thing, my view model does not know anything about it.

My solouion:
using DisposableEffect
so on Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP , I stop media player

Comment: Thank you Philip,yes this answer is very similar to my issue

Comment: You're welcome! If it solved your question, you can mark this question as duplicate, and give [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68962907/3585796) an upvote =)

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a single activity, always override the `onDestroy()` method of the activity lifecycle to dispose of everything when your app is killed (either by the user or by the system to save resources).

```
override fun onDestroy(){
 mediaPlayer.release()
 super.onDestroy()
}
```

Now, your ideology of "viewmodel knows nothing of the UI" is lethal.
Please take the [State in Compose](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state) codelab paying special attention to the part explaining [state-hoisting](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state#8).

Comment: I need to know about lifecycle of screen to release media player resource when user leave screen. so I resolved the problem with DisposableEffect from here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects
And you right about ondestroy() but I create media player in different screen and my activity contain five screen so that wasn't a good idea.

Comment: Thank you about introduce state code lab, I will take that.

Comment: Well, you should consider adding that info (five screens and separate activities) so that people can answer specifically to your use-case. Anyway, I'm glad your issue is resolved!

Answer (score 0):

if I get right you have to create a funtion and use androidview to wrap the mediaplayer component, but if what you want is to load a media file you have to place it in res/raw and access throught context, to get the context in a compose function you have to use LocalContext.current

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis?hl=en-419

Comment: Thank you, but no you didn't get right. I need to know about lifecycle of screen to release media player resource when user leave screen. so I resolved the problem with DisposableEffect from here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects