# Jetpack Compose - Processing after completion of composition

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a composable that displays information on the device. I need to play a sound clip automatically, AFTER the the composable has been composed and the information is rendered on the screen. Where do I put this function call?

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68962907/3585796)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Thanks a lot! That perfectly addresses my issue :)